# Changing a variable whose address is in stack

Tags: assembly, x86, masm, irvine32

so let's say this is my main

```
main PROC
    sub esp, 4
    push OFFSET variableName
    call changeVariable

changeVariable PROC
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
```

How can I change variableName to a different value (say, 10) in the changeVariable procedure?

I tried

```
mov OFFSET[ebp+8], 10  ;ebp[+8] is the position in stack that holds address of variableName
```

but that doesn't work

Comment: You need another dereference.  Load the address into a scratch register and then deref that.

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your try,

```
mov OFFSET[ebp+8], 10
```

Indirect or indexed operands are invalid for the `OFFSET` operator, i think you have misunderstood the return value of `OFFSET` which is an immediate operand, "effective address of data", also the return value of an `OFFSET` operator would make the destination operand of the `MOV` instruction an immediate operand which is invalid.

In your case if you have an offset of `variableName` already on the stack, first load the offset in a temporary register and just use an indirect operand dereference but you have to specify the the size by using `PTR` operator.

```
mov esi,[ebp+8]
mov DWORD PTR[esi],10
```

Comment: Haha! No problem. I've been in the "Ooops I have been testing the wrong program" situation before ;-). I'll delete my earlier comments now

Answer (score 2):

You are pushing a pointer, as noted in the comment you need to deference it.
Refer to [this Godbolt example](https://godbolt.org/z/cFAkza) where this C code

```
void bar(int* c)
{
    *c = 10;
}

void foo(int c)
{
        c = 10;
}

int myVar;

int main()
{
    bar(&myVar);

    foo(myVar);
}
```

is assembled into

```
bar:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp

        ;What you need to do:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [ebp+8]     ;Read the pointer
        mov     DWORD PTR [eax], 10        ;Deference it

        nop
        pop     ebp
        ret

foo:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp

        ;What you are doing:
        mov     DWORD PTR [ebp+8], 10  ;Overwriting an argument

        nop
        pop     ebp
        ret

main:
        push    ebp
        mov     ebp, esp

        ;This is you call exactly
        push    OFFSET FLAT:myVar
        call    bar
        add     esp, 4

        ;How one would call the foo version
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR myVar
        push    eax
        call    foo
        add     esp, 4


        mov     eax, 0
        leave
        ret
```

Pay particular attention to what C code `foo` and `bar` correspond to.
This may help you understand the differences.